# Prove that $B/A$ is a normal subgroup of $C/A$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $A$ is a subgroup of $B$, $B$ is a subgroup of $C$, and $A,B,C$ are normal subgroup of $G$. Is $C/A$ a normal subgroup of $G/A$?...

I do this:

Let $\gamma:G \rightarrow G/A$ a natural homomorphism, then $\gamma B=B/A$ is a normal subgroup of $G/A$. Likewise $\gamma:C\rightarrow C/A$ is a normal subgroup of $G/A$. Then $B/A$ is a subgroup of $C/A$ because $C$ is a subgroup of $C$, but how can I prove that $B/A$ is (or not) a normal subgroup of $C/A$?? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows at once from the Correspondence Theorem:

$$B\lhd G\implies \forall\,b\in B\;,\;\forall\, g\in G\;,\;\;b^g:=g^{-1}bg\in B\implies$$

$$(bC)^{gC}:=(gC)^{-1}bC(gC)=g^{-1}CbCgC:=(g^{-1}bg)C\in B/A\implies B/A\lhd C/A$$

Comment: Why $(g^-1 b g)C$ es in $B/A$??? P.D. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @JoeBecause $\;g^{-1}bg\;$ is in $\;B\;$ , for **any** $\;b\in B\;,\;\;g\in G\;$ , since $\;B\lhd G\;$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $G/A\to G/C$, $gA\mapsto gC$ is well-defined and that its kernel is $C/A$.

Comment: Sorry I dont get it

Comment: @Joe, remember: a subgroup of $\;G\;$ is normal in it iff it is the kernel of some homomorphism from $\;G\;$ .